# Can Jekyll 3.0.x _include_ the index.html in page.url

Tags: jekyll

Seen many questions asking how to omit `index.html` in previous versions of Jekyll, but I do *want* to include it.

Is there any config variable or other to make Jekyll 3.0.x include it?

By page I'm refering to the object you get when doing something like

```
<ul>
{% for page in site.pages %}
  <li>{{ page.url }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Not to the current page.

Found this solution, but it's not very practical:

```
    {% assign last_url_char = page.url | split: '' | last %}
    {% if last_url_char == '/' %}
    {%    assign page_url = page.url | append: "index.html" %}
    {% else %}
    {%    assign page_url = page.url %}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: There should be a permalink setting that fits what you want, what is the permalink value in _config.yml and what are some examples of the URLs you want for pages and posts? By default Jekyll includes the .html unless you have changed it.

Comment: had permalink: /blog/:slug:output_ext in _config.yml, but, afaik, it only affects posts, not static pages. There's no other permalink in any page / post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the .html extension in the permalinks setting:

```
 permalink: /blog/:slug.html
```

Then all the pages will have that extension.

### update

Create a fresh 3.0 install:

```
$ jekyll _3.0_ new mysite
$ cd mysite
```

Edit `about.html` and remove the custom permalink to see the changes after we generate pages with the `.html` extension:

```
---
layout: page
title: About
permalink: /about/    <--- delete
---
```

Specify different permalinks for *pages* and *posts* in `_config.yml`:

```
defaults:
 -   
  scope:
    type: pages
  values:
    permalink: /:path/:basename:output_ext
 -   
  scope:
    type: posts
  values:
    permalink: /:year/:month/:day/:title.html
```

Add the following code to `index.html` to see the available pages and its urls:

```
<p>Current page: {{page.url}}</p>

{% for my_page in site.pages %}
{% if my_page.title %}
url: {{my_page.url }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now serve the website `$ jekyll _3.0_ serve` and access to http://localhost:4000/index.html

Comment: Sorry but, at least in my environment (Jekyll 3.0.1), it does not work. The /index.html page gets a `page.url` value of "/"

Comment: Made a test with a "on liner", same result: cd /tmp/; jekyll new j; cd j; echo -e '---\n---\n{{ page.url }}' > index.html; echo permalink: /blog/:slug.html >> _config.yml; jekyll build; cat _site/index.html

Comment: Updated the answer, pages are not being generated as expected, so now I have explicitely chose a permalink for them